# How to add additional field names in to selected label in React Select?

Tags: reactjs

I have a react select control. When I select an option; I wanted to append additional field values into selected label. For eg: In list it showing "FirstName". After select I wanted to append "LastName" also along with "FirstName". Means the selected value should be like "FirstName"+"LastName".
How it is possible in React-Select?

Comment: Where to add onChange()?

Comment: In dropdown it showing firstname.